# It is possible to copy the server certificate to attackers server to misuse it?

Tags: security, encryption, certificate, pki, x509

I aks myself if it is possible to copy the server certificate to another server to misuse it. Example: An attacker visits https website X and copies the X.509 certificate. He placed the stolen X.509 certificate on his own server and would like being trustworthy.

Of course, the attacker does not have the private key, but the private key is only required to decrypt the encrypted message from the client. In terms of authentification there is no reason to be doubtfully. Or?

The server responses with the X.509 certificate. The client receives the certificate and validates successfully using the stored root certificates. Why should the server not be authentificated? Only when the client sends an encrypted message using the public key the server is not able to decrypt the message - because he does not own the private key.

It is right so far?

Comment: You are wrong but kind of close to the truth and I encourage you to keep chugging along. Bear in mind that there are two general classes of ciphersuites that should be studied separately: Pure RSA and ephemeral diffie-hellman. Study the RFCs, rfc 2246 and its successors. The SSL connection is not authenticated until a validated FINISHED message is received from the peer.

Answer (score 4):

> Only when the client sends an encrypted message using the public key the server is not able to decrypt the message - because he does not own the private key.

The server also needs the private key to sign messages being sent to the client.

The SSL/TLS handshake protocol itself effectively involves such an authenticated message being sent to the client. If the private key is unavailable then this step will fail before any 'real' payload message gets sent.

Answer (score 1):

> Why should the server not be authentificated?

The certificate is tied to a domain name.

The web browser will download the certificate and validate it. One of the steps in the validation is to compare the domain the certificate is for to the domain that the browser actually downloaded it from. If there is a mismatch (and there will be, since the attacker is on their own domain, not the original site's domain) then the browser will present the user with a certificate error and ask them to make the call about whether or not to accept it.

You're probably used to seeing this in action on bad web server configurations. Ever seen an error saying, "This certificate was intended for www.example.com" when you were trying to visit "example.com"?

> Of course, the attacker does not have the private key, but the private key is only required to decrypt the encrypted message from the client.

Public/private key pairs have other uses than that. In this case, the private key signs the certificate and the public key verifies it. There is no encryption involved. (What you described is more like a normal encryption scheme, like RSA.)

Comment: Domain spoofing is an attempt to convince the browser that a resource came from a domain that it did not actually come from. This could indeed allow a stolen certificate to be used.

Comment: Even after spoofing the domain, an attacker cannot use just the public key to trick the client. If she could, then SSL would be pointless. See @bobince's answer. In order to negotiate an SSL session, the server must have access to the private key.

Comment: The server's private key, not the CA's private key. To clarify: Domain spoofing will allow a browser to download a HTTPS certificate and validate it came from the specified the domain, but it won't allow for the full negotiation of the TLS session. (I'm not sure what UI error the user is likely to see in that case.)

Answer (score 0):

No, the certificate is a pubic element and it is just a way to bind a public key to a name (here, a DNS name). During the authentication process (in the TLS protocol) the server sends its certificate along with signs some data with the associated private key. In order to verify that the server is the legitimate owner of the certificate, the client have to verify the validity of this signature with the sent certificate. A rogue server can try to use the certificate but without the private key it cannot prove it is the real holder.